# How to set default body message for Privatemsg embedded on page?

Tags: privatemsg

This is the code I used on the node template and block, I just tried it both

module_load_include('pages.inc','privatemsg');

$recipients = array(user_load(arg(1)));

$subject = 'This is just a default that can be changed';

**$body = 'Again, this is just a default that can be changed';**

print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('privatemsg_new', $recipients, $subject, **$body**));

The **Bold** ones are the codes I added from the orginal code I got from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/624528

But I'm getting this message when I added the $body:

> You can not reply to this conversation because all recipients are
> blocked.

I've looked into the parameter of privatemsg and it says that the $body is the body text of the new message.

I would like to put some default body message on the embedded privatemsg.

I tried to edit the body via custom module, still no luck for me. I'm not sure where I went wrong.. here's the code on the custom module

```
function sassy_hook_form_privatemsg_new_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['privatemsg_new']['body'] = array(             
    '#type' => 'textarea',      
    '#title' => t('Message'),       
    '#rows' => 6,       
    '#weight' => 0,         
    '#default_value' =>  t('Message'),      
    '#resizable' => TRUE,   );   
}
```

I also tried $form_state['values']['body'] = 'Hello World';

Is there any way to do this?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the descriptor of [the `privatemsg_new` function](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.pages.inc/function/privatemsg_new/7) in privatemsg.pages.inc:

```
privatemsg_new($form, &$form_state, $recipients = '', $subject = '')
```

It doesn't take a `$body` argument so you will need to alter the form once it has been created.

1. [Make a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7)
2. Use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)
3. Set $form_state['values']['body'] to your desired value

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is it possible to use that code on a block or node.tpl.php only? I'm trying to avoid creating a module because I'm still basic at drupal.

Comment: No it is not possible, because the function you are trying to use won't let you add a `$body` to it. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try to make it work with a custom module. :)

Comment: Hi @Darvanen, I tried to edit the body, still no luck for me. I'm not sure where I went wrong.. here's the code on the custom module  `function sassy_hook_form_privatemsg_new_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    $form['privatemsg_new']['body'] = array(
   
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Message'),
  '#rows' => 6,
  '#weight' => 0,
  '#default_value' =>  t('Message'),
  '#resizable' => TRUE,
  );
  
}  `               I also tried $form_state['values']['body'] = 'Hello World';

Comment: Best to adjust your question, a bit hard to read here.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice attempt with the module, but you have a bit more to [learn about hooks](https://www.drupal.org/node/292).

1. Your module name should *replace* the word 'hook' in the function name (case sensitive).
2. Make sure you turn on the module and clear caches before testing so that Drupal knows the hook is there.

You might find that `$form['privatemsg_new']['body']` is the wrong place to be putting your new item, but once the hook registers you'll be able to play around with it until you get it right.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for guiding me! I'll try it again. :)